# Phonegap: Contact list Sorting

Tags: android, cordova, sorting, phonegap-plugins

In phone gap I fetch all the contact details. After fetch all the details i try to sort the list based on the alphabetical order of name.Its sorted , but its taking around 30 sec to sort all the list.How to optimize the list.

```
function onSuccess(contacts) 
   {
    contacts = contacts.sort(cSort);
   }

  var cSort = function(a, b) {
          aName = a.displayName ;
          bName = b.displayName ;
            return aName < bName ? -1 : (aName == bName ? 0 : 1);
        };
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorting the contacts to display them, why not just use an ng-repeat, a and an orderBy filter?

That would optimise things immensely!